# Suppress the Curl command output (not progress meter)

Tags: python-2.7, curl

All,

I have wrote the below statement to call a webservice from my python code .
I am only storing this response in a variable.

```
 responseVariable = subprocess.check_output(["curl", "-k", "-s" ,  '--data-binary' ,etree.tostring(root) , "https://world-service-dev.intra.aexp.com:4414/worldservice/CLIC/CaseManagementService/V1"],stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

However when I run this script , the whole response Soap XML gets printed on the console . By using option "-s" I could suppress the progress meter . But how to I stop curl from printing the whole response .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce the issue you're having, using the same code as you with the url and data replaced does not result in any console output when running the python script.
The error is not in the line of code you've shared. As you can check by running this command on your python commandline

```
a=subprocess.check_output(["curl", "-s", '--data-binary',''
                         ,"http://www.google.com"], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

No output is produced and `a` will contain the data returned by the webservice.

Comment: thats strange as I am not printing the output anywhere in my code . Is it because I am getting a soap response?

Comment: I got the problem... Apologies... The program which was calling it was actually prinitng it.. silly mistake.